# Subfig causing a mess in List of Tables/Figures

Tags: table-of-contents, pdftex, miktex, subfloats

OK, this was introduced with a very recent update to MikTeX but it is a big problem for me... - I narrowed it down to the subfig package - and yes, I need it for subfloats with numbering... however it now does this:

```
\contentsline {table}{\numberline {3.1{table}}{\ignorespaces List of orders of reactions with the appropriate units for the rate constant.\relax }}{39}{table.caption.16}
```

This shows up as 3.1table List of order ...
-> That "table" (or figure for figures) did not use to show up, suddenly it does, I need to get rid of it.

Any solutions?

For those desperate for an example, it shows up in something as simple as this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{subfig}


\begin{document}

\listoftables

\begin{table}%
\begin{tabular}{lcr}
entry1 & entry 2 & entry 3 \\
\end{tabular}
\caption{}
\label{}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This is a `caption` package issue apparently. Please update

Comment: I have no issue with the MWE

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Indeed - and I updated not too long ago... Well, thankfully a simple solution. Any chance you can post this as an answer I can accept?

Comment: @DetlevCM: That would be easy reputation ;-) ... The issue occured some days ago with some update, but A. Sommerfeldt (Author of `caption`) fixed the bug quickly in the next update already

Comment: @ChristianHupfer And what is wrong with that if you have pointed out/provided the correct solution? - I tried updating the file name database, refreshing formats... - Looked at which package caused the issue (and thankfully found it) - but never thought to check the updates (again - did so a couple of days ago).

Comment: @DetlevCM: Done so ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The package `caption` has shown some issues some days ago, being connected to a previous update, showing `3table` etc in the LoT etc.

A. Sommerfeldt updated again and the issue is gone.

The solution here is to update specifically the `caption` package for the relevant TeX distribution (MikTeX, TeXLive etc.)